# Any testing tools that can test a PowerBuilder app and a webapp?

Tags: testing, powerbuilder

I'm working on developing a webapp that will replace an existing PowerBuilder app. They should be functionality equivalent, and the requirements for the PB app are long gone. So the best way to test seems to be to input the same data into the same screens, and compare the output. If the PB output and the webapp output are the same, it's functionally equivalent.

Is there a testing tool/framework that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP QuickTestPro, IBM Rational Robot are 2 tools that support both web testing and PowerBuilder apps.  You may want to peruse the test tool forums at [sqaforums](http://www.sqaforums.com).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how deep you are into your development, but have you thought about looking at Appeon?  It allows you to deploy your PowerBuilder application directly over the browser.  I'm not talking about reconfiguring your application in order to deploy webforms.  Appeon will allow your app to run (for the most part) as is.  Your app looks completely the same.  Just in a browser.

Just thought I would throw that in here just in case you either had not started or were not too deep into anything yet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We can test the PB Application through the PBUnit and PBTest its free from Sybase Code Exchange.

PBUnit - has some probs thats external ancestor script references

PBTest - it is working

Both are Test frame works it may helps you..